# OutlinedBorder class to create custom button shape

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-design

I need help understanding how creating a custom shape in Flutter using the `OutlinedBorder` class works.

I don't want to use clipping because I want to test if a custom shape would preferably not clip the button child as well.

I would prefer if someone would explain using an easier shape but here's what I created:

[image]

It sort works well enough that only the blue part would react to a click and the ripples don't leak out, but there's two stars and I want it to be just a single star.

Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'dart:math' as Math;

class StarShape extends OutlinedBorder {
  final BorderSide side;

  StarShape({
    this.side = const BorderSide(),
  });

  @override
  OutlinedBorder copyWith({BorderSide? side}) {
    return StarShape(side: side ?? const BorderSide());
  }

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.all(10);

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    var _path = Path()
      ..addRect(rect.deflate(25))
      ..close();
    return _path;
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    rect = rect.inflate(15);
    var mid = rect.width / 2;
    var min = Math.min(rect.width, rect.height);
    var half = min / 2;
    mid = mid - half;
    var path = Path();
// top left
    path.moveTo(mid + half * 0.5, half * 0.84);
// top right
    path.lineTo(mid + half * 1.5, half * 0.84);
// bottom left
    path.lineTo(mid + half * 0.68, half * 1.45);
// top tip
    path.lineTo(mid + half * 1.0, half * 0.5);
// bottom right
    path.lineTo(mid + half * 1.32, half * 1.45);
// top left
    path.lineTo(mid + half * 0.5, half * 0.84);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    var mid = rect.width / 2;
    var min = Math.min(rect.width, rect.height);
    var half = min / 2;
    mid = mid - half;


    var path = Path();
// top left
    path.moveTo(mid + half * 0.5, half * 0.84);
// top right
    path.lineTo(mid + half * 1.5, half * 0.84);
// bottom left
    path.lineTo(mid + half * 0.68, half * 1.45);
// top tip
    path.lineTo(mid + half * 1.0, half * 0.5);
// bottom right
    path.lineTo(mid + half * 1.32, half * 1.45);
// top left
    path.lineTo(mid + half * 0.5, half * 0.84);
    canvas.drawPath(
      path,
      Paint()..color = Colors.amber,
    );
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) {
    return this.scale(t);
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to remove the yellow star or make 2 stars as a 1star?

Comment: @shorol I drew one star. I think the two stars showing up is because one of the layers was too big and so it got displaced by a few pixels.
The one I drew is the amber coloured star. The one that's clickable is the blue star. I did not intend to draw the blue star.